# New Relic not picking up the @Trace annotation class defined

Tags: newrelic

I am referring this New Relic document to write my own @Trace annotation class with New Relic Java agent.

https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/java-agent/java-agent-api/java-agent-api-instrument-using-annotation#web-request

I created a class and used the class name on the yaml file in 
class_transformer:
  trace_annotation_class_name:

But this is not picking up by New Relic. I am not seeing any Track trace details.

Comment: Could you please provide a snippet of code?